# Why are my colors separated/shifted when using obs/v4l2sink/v4l2loopback?

Tags: video, obs-studio, v4l

Im using OBS with v4l2sink and v4l2loopback to edit my video for a remote trainig.
The preview in obs looks fine, but the video has some serious color shifts in any tool I try to display the v4l2loopack I'm directing the sink to.

View from OBS:
[image: View from OBS]

View from Browser:
[image: View from Browser]
You can see that all colors have a green shadow about half the grid width.
Is there any setting that I could change to fix this?
The video format selected in the V4l2sinkProperties is YUV420 as all others result in "format not supported"

I run Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Linux 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64). OBS Studio is 25.0.8 installed via apt. obs-v4l2sink and v4lsloopback are built and installed from the current GitHub sources.

Comment: What OS/release, and how did you install OBS?  (inc. version if a *snap* etc)

Comment: I run Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Linux 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64). OBS Studio is 25.0.8 installed via apt. obs-v4l2sink and v4lsloopback are built and installed from the current GitHub sources.

Comment: Please add any important information directly to your question: use "edit". Comments may disappear, and may not be read by potential helpers.

Comment: Hi, im having the same problem but from the obs-studio snap
> snap info obs-studio
To make use of the V4L2Sink plugin, install and configure `v4l2loopback` as follows:
  
     sudo apt -y install v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2loopback-utils
     echo "options v4l2loopback devices=1 video_nr=99 card_label=VirtualCam exclusive_caps=1"  | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/v4l2loopback.conf
     echo "v4l2loopback" | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/v4l2loopback.conf
     sudo modprobe -r v4l2loopback
     sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 video_nr=99 card_label=VirtualCam exclusive_caps=1

Comment: After fiddling with the resolutions, I got it to work now. Apparently some combination of input and output resolutions did not work well.

Comment: where and how you change the resolution?

Comment: For the camera: v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 --set-fmt-video=width=1920,height=1080.    The rest: in OBS

Comment: I fixed it by changing video format to YUY2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the format to **YUY2** and set the same dimensions on OBS and v4l2 device.

I solve my issue of "not supported format" by:

1. removing v4l2loopback-**utils** and then installing v4l2loopback-**dkms**
2. set YUY2 on v4l2sink menu

The credits are for https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink/issues/5#issuecomment-618336414